# Vim auto-indent behaves strangely after multiline comment

Tags: vim, macvim, auto-indent

I have this piece of PHP-code:

```
    } elseif($uri->next() == "list"){
      bla();
      /*****************************************
       * Get empty relation by type             *
       * ====================================== *
       * GET /api.php?/relations/(string)/list  *
       ******************************************/
  //get a list of all relations with the specified type.
  $rel->giveRelationsOfType($relationType);
    } elseif($uri->end()){
```

and it's indentation is automatically done exactly in the way shown above. I would of course want everything within my elseif-block to be indented to the same column as "bla", like this:

```
    } elseif($uri->next() == "list"){
      bla();
      /*****************************************
       * Get empty relation by type             *
       * ====================================== *
       * GET /api.php?/relations/(string)/list  *
       ******************************************/
      //get a list of all relations with the specified type.
      $rel->giveRelationsOfType($relationType);
    } elseif($uri->end()){
```

but when I select the whole block (visual mode) and press `=`, the indentation changes back to that of my first example. I tried several variations of the above; having a multi-line comment seems to be the thing the strange indentation depends on.

My formatoptions (`set fo?`) are `2qwcbro`. (press `:h fo-table` for info)
In my `vimrc` I have

```
set smartindent
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
```

However, `set smartindent` seems to be turned off by my filetype or something, even though it does indent correctly when typing a return after a `{`. Turning smartindent on doesn't help.